# Create hibernate transaction with transaction isolation different from default

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 5.12.17 as an orm. I am not using other java frameworks which interface with hibernate(So no Spring).

So the question is: how do i create a transaction which has the  Isolation Level "Serializable"?

I don't want to change the default Isolation for all my hibernate using code, I just have a few queries which need to run with a different isolation level from the rest of my app.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use these ways:

1. Use `Query.lockMode(String alias, LockMode lockMode)`. You can find in the reference at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setLockMode(java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.LockMode)) link.
2. Use `Session.load(Class theClass, Serializable id, LockMode lockMode)`. You can find the reference [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable,%20org.hibernate.LockMode)).
3. Use one of the `Session.lock(..)` methods.

Comment: How can the lock method change isolation level? Don't it just use an "For update" query?

Comment: Isolation level is about how you lock the record(s) on which you perform the operation. The query lock does similar thing, with the difference that the scope of the lock is specific for that query.